# Google Chrome extension restarting itself

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension for a client. Everything has always run smoothly on my end, but when they run it on their computer, there has always been little glitches that were never repeatable (**so annoying**). Yesterday, I finially nailed down (hopefully) the last piece of the puzzle—on there machine, the extenssion is restarting itself mid browsing session. I know I never explicitly coded this in myself, and I have never experienced it on my own machine. To clarify, the type of restart that's happening (as there are at least 3 different types of restarts) seems to be the same as refreshing the background page—storage is kept in tact and `onInstall` handlers are not run. Anyone have any idea what could be causing such an issue?

The code is too big to post here, but I can try to post some snippits of it if anyone wants to see where a specific API is used or something.

Comment: The only relevant API methods are chrome.runtime.restart and restartAfterDelay. If you're not using those, it means there's a bug in your code (or in Chrome). Try using [logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and [extension activity monitor](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/23/google-chrome-activity-log-for-extensions/) as well as the usual methods such as verbose logging in every function/method of your code.

Comment: @wOxxOm those are definitely not used anywhere. If those are the only APIs that can do that, how could a bug in my code cause this to happen? Wouldn't that imply there are ways to restart an extension other than the APIs you just listed?

Comment: Without seeing what exactly happens during that "restart" we can't say it's even the same restart as the API provides. Maybe something crashes, maybe something else. You need to investigate first what happens using the methods I've described.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm actually now thinking it might be as simple as `persistent` being set to `false`.

Comment: It cannot be changed dynamically so not sure what you mean by "being set".

Comment: @wOxxOm I meant I have it set to false in `manifest.json`

Comment: I don't see how this setting is related to the problem. Which is why questions without [MCVE](/help/mcve) aren't really answerable.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have state stored in the background script variables. This state is getting ruined because the background script is refreshing somehow. My guess is that this is happening because persistent is set to false. Either way, I'm just going to rebuild the extension to store state in the storage APIs because I think that's the suggested method anyway, after reviews what it says on Google's website.

Comment: 1) The background script can't refresh "somehow" - the only reason is a bug in the code or in the browser. I suggest investigating the problem, not blindly guessing and making changes. 2) Just because the documentation says so in general, doesn't mean it really is in your particular case. If the state is expensive to calculate then a persistent:true script is the right choice.

Comment: @wOxxOm well unfortunately the problem never happens on my machine, only my client's, I can't meet with them in person so debugging is very tedious. The state isn't too crazy, so I think the best course of action is to just use the storage api.

Comment: I'm working on a chrome extension and I have the same problem! `background.js` is run again for no apparent reason and it's been driving me crazy!

Comment: @SimonBerens try the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I'm pretty sure the problem was what I speculated about in the comments. I needed to set `persistent` to `true` in my `manifest.json`. Having it set to `false` means the background script "goes to sleep". I believe it going to sleep and waking back up was the restart I was experiencing.